# How to implement Markdown Extra on Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, markdown

I want to install markdown extra because it has some features I like. But, the codeigniter version only uses the normal markdown how can I use the markdown extra on codeigniter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeIgniter haves markdown by default? I just downloaded `Markdown_extra.php`, renamed it to `Markdown_helper.php` and put it inside `application/helpers`.

Then you only need to load it using `$this->load->helper('markdown')` and call it with `Markdown($string)`

Comment: No, but it has this library: https://github.com/vamsiikrishna/cimarkdown
and dang I feel dumb for not thinking that so obvious. Thanks!